# Why exactly is "obese" not matched with an index value?

Tags: python, loops

For the section of code between "elif" and "obese", I'm just a bit confused about how exactly that works. Would anyone mind explaining how? I know that the "obese" value is printed outside of the while loop but I'm not entirely sure how that segment all fits together. I know the index increases by one once the loop finishes. Also, I understand how the two lists match together, except for obese. Thank you!

```
BMIList = ["severly underweight", "underweight", "healthy", "overweight", "obese"]
BMIValues = [15.99, 18.49, 24.99, 29.99, 500]
print("Welcome to BMI Calculator!")
print("Enter I for Imperial or M for Metric")

def healthindex (preference, bmi):
 if preference == "b":
   print("BMI " + str(round(bmi,2)))
 elif preference == "h":
   index = 0
   print("your BMI is " + str(round(bmi,2)))
   while index < len(BMIList):
     if bmi < BMIValues[index]:
       print ("And, you are " + BMIList[index])
       return
     index = index + 1
   print("You are Obese")
 else:
   print("Invalid choice")
 Return
```

Comment: Your while loop is checking **all** values, even the value for *"obese"*.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the `bmi < BMIValues[index]` conditions are true, the function prints the corresponding element of `BMIList` and returns.

If the BMI is higher than all the `BMIValues` elements, you get out of the loop and print `You are Obese` as a default.

BTW, this would be a good opportunity to use `zip()` to iterate over two lists together:

```
for bmi_value, condition in zip(BMIValues, BMIList):
    if bmi < bmi_value:
        print("And you are " + condition)
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

The "obese" index match if the value of bmi is between 29.99 and 500. The reason for "you are obese" that is outside of the while loop is to handle values larger than 500. You could use float("inf") instead of 500 to handle all cases.